# @ViewChild not working in angular-google-charts with error "chart is undefined"

Tags: angular, google-visualization

I'm trying to access the underlying ChartWrapper using the instructions provided in https://github.com/FERNman/angular-google-charts#advanced but can't get it to work as I get the error that "Chart is undefined"

I have tried replacing ngOnInit() with other Angular Lifecycle hook ngAfterViewInit() and ngAfterContentInit() but still the same result.

component.html

```html
<google-chart #chart *ngIf="height"></google-chart>
```

component.ts

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { GoogleChartComponent } from 'angular-google-charts'

@Component({
...
})
export class TimelineComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('chart', {static: true}) 
  chart: GoogleChartComponent

  ngOnInit() {
    this.someService.getHeight().subscribe((data: any) => {
      this.height = data
    })
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const wrapper = this.chart.wrapper
    console.log(wrapper)
  }
}
```

I expect to see the underlying ChartWrapper that I can use in my code.

Comment: If you remove the *ngIf, is the wrapper still undefined? The component might not be rendered yet on ngAfterViewInit.
Something else you can try is try getting it the wrapper inside of the subscribe callback.

Comment: If I remove *ngIf, then I can see the wrapper. However *ngIf has to be there because the data for the chart comes from a Service. For your other suggestion, can you give me a piece of code example to try please

Comment: if you check it after `height` has been set in callback and if `height` is truthy, you should be able to access the wrapper there?

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you will want to use **{static: false}** in your ViewChild. Setting it like this will ensure query matches that are dependent on binding resolution (like structural directives *ngIf, etc...) will be found.

So the answer would be this:

```
  *@ViewChild('chart', {static: false})*
```

The *static: false* is going to be the default fallback behaviour in Angular 9.

The { static: true } option was introduced to support creating embedded views on the fly. When you are creating a view dynamically and want to acces the TemplateRef, you won't be able to do so in ngAfterViewInit as it will cause a ExpressionHasChangedAfterChecked error. Setting the static flag to true will create your view in ngOnInit.

Comment: Thanks Miroslav, I have tried changing static to false but still same problem. Does not work and shows "chart is undefined". Any other suggestions?

Comment: Then try to remove *ngIf from the element as it destroys your DOM somehow.
And try to hide it by css with some properties like visibility: false etc which won't remove the element from DOM and then it will be accessible by ViewChild.